# Laravel 7.3.0, как локализовать (ru) формат даты (Carbon)?

Tags: laravel, carbon

Не могу разобраться с локализацией формата даты. Для вывода, конечно, использую Carbon. В настройках стоит нужная локаль (`'locale' => 'ru'`).

Вывожу дату в формате `\Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->published_at)->format('j F Y')`, получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Погуглил нашел два пакет

1. [localized-carbon](https://github.com/LaravelRUS/localized-carbon) - морально устарел.
2. [jenssegers/date](https://github.com/jenssegers/date) - в релизах видно, что добавлена минимальная поддержка Laravel 7. Но при попытке установить валиться куча ошибок.

---

```bsh
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v2.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v2.0.1
    - symfony/translation 4.2.x-dev requires symfony/contracts ^1.1.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/contracts[v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v1.1.3, v1.1.4, v1.1.5, v1.1.6, v1.1.7, v1.1.8].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.10 requires symfony/contracts ^1.1.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/contracts[v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v1.1.3, v1.1.4, v1.1.5, v1.1.6, v1.1.7, v1.1.8].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.11 requires symfony/contracts ^1.1.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/contracts[v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v1.1.3, v1.1.4, v1.1.5, v1.1.6, v1.1.7, v1.1.8].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.12 requires symfony/contracts ^1.1.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/contracts[v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v1.1.3, v1.1.4, v1.1.5, v1.1.6, v1.1.7, v1.1.8].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.9 requires symfony/contracts ^1.1.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/contracts[v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v1.1.3, v1.1.4, v1.1.5, v1.1.6, v1.1.7, v1.1.8].
    - don't install symfony/contracts v1.1.1|don't install symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v2.0.1
    - don't install symfony/contracts v1.1.2|don't install symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v2.0.1
    - don't install symfony/contracts v1.1.3|don't install symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v2.0.1
    - don't install symfony/contracts v1.1.4|don't install symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v2.0.1
    - don't install symfony/contracts v1.1.5|don't install symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v2.0.1
    - don't install symfony/contracts v1.1.6|don't install symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v2.0.1
    - don't install symfony/contracts v1.1.7|don't install symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v2.0.1
    - don't install symfony/contracts v1.1.8|don't install symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v2.0.1
    - Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (locked at v2.0.1) -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts[v2.0.1].
    - Installation request for jenssegers/date ^3.5 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/date[v3.5.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-kernel v5.0.5|install symfony/translation 4.2.x-dev|install symfony/translation v4.2.10|install symfony/translation v4.2.11|install symfony/translation v4.2.12|install symfony/translation v4.2.9
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/http-kernel v5.0.5|install symfony/translation 4.2.x-dev|install symfony/translation v4.2.10|install symfony/translation v4.2.11|install symfony/translation v4.2.12|install symfony/translation v4.2.9
    - jenssegers/date v3.5.0 requires symfony/translation ^2.7|^3.0|^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/translation[2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev, 3.1.x-dev, 3.2.x-dev, 3.3.x-dev, 3.4.x-dev, 4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, 4.3.x-dev, 4.4.x-dev, v2.7.0, v2.7.0-BETA1, v2.7.0-BETA2, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.42, v2.7.43, v2.7.44, v2.7.45, v2.7.46, v2.7.47, v2.7.48, v2.7.49, v2.7.5, v2.7.50, v2.7.51, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.0-BETA1, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.5, v2.8.50, v2.8.52, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.0.0, v3.0.0-BETA1, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.0-BETA1, v3.1.0-RC1, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.0-BETA1, v3.2.0-RC1, v3.2.0-RC2, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.0-BETA1, v3.3.0-RC1, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.0-BETA1, v3.4.0-BETA2, v3.4.0-BETA3, v3.4.0-BETA4, v3.4.0-RC1, v3.4.0-RC2, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.3, v3.4.30, v3.4.31, v3.4.32, v3.4.33, v3.4.34, v3.4.35, v3.4.36, v3.4.37, v3.4.38, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA1, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.0-RC1, v4.0.0-RC2, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13, v4.0.14, v4.0.15, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.0-BETA1, v4.1.0-BETA2, v4.1.0-BETA3, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.0-BETA1, v4.2.0-BETA2, v4.2.0-RC1, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.3.0, v4.3.0-BETA1, v4.3.0-BETA2, v4.3.0-RC1, v4.3.1, v4.3.10, v4.3.11, v4.3.2, v4.3.3, v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8, v4.3.9, v4.4.0, v4.4.0-BETA1, v4.4.0-BETA2, v4.4.0-RC1, v4.4.1, v4.4.2, v4.4.3, v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v4.4.6].
    - symfony/translation 4.0.x-dev conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation 4.1.x-dev conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation 4.3.x-dev conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation 4.4.x-dev conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.0 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.0-BETA2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.0-BETA3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.0-BETA4 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.0-RC2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.10 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.11 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.12 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.13 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.14 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.15 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.4 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.5 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.6 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.7 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.8 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.0.9 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.0 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.0-BETA2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.0-BETA3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.10 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.11 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.12 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.4 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.5 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.6 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.7 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.8 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.1.9 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.0 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.0-BETA2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.4 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.5 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.6 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.7 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.2.8 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.0 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.0-BETA2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.10 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.11 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.4 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.5 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.6 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.7 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.8 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.3.9 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.4.0 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.4.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.4.0-BETA2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.4.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.4.1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.4.2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.4.3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.4.4 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.4.5 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v4.4.6 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation 3.4.x-dev conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.0 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.0-BETA2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.0-BETA3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.0-BETA4 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.0-RC2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.10 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.11 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.12 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.13 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.14 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.15 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.16 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.17 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.18 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.19 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.20 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.21 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.23 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.24 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.25 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.26 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.27 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.28 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.29 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.30 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.31 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.32 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.33 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.34 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.35 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.36 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.37 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.38 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.4 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.5 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.6 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.7 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.8 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.4.9 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation 2.7.x-dev conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation 2.8.x-dev conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation 3.0.x-dev conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation 3.1.x-dev conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation 3.2.x-dev conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation 3.3.x-dev conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.0 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.0-BETA2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.10 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.11 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.12 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.13 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.14 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.15 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.16 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.17 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.18 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.19 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.20 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.21 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.23 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.24 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.25 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.26 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.27 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.28 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.29 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.30 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.31 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.32 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.33 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.34 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.35 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.36 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.37 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.38 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.39 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.4 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.40 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.41 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.42 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.43 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.44 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.45 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.46 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.47 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.48 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.49 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.5 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.50 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.51 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.6 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.7 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v2.7.8 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.0.0 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.0.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.0.1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.0.2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.0.3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.0.4 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.0.5 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.0.6 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.0.7 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.0.8 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.0.9 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.1.0 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.1.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.1.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.1.1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.1.10 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.1.2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.1.3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.1.4 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.1.5 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.1.6 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.1.7 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.1.8 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.1.9 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.0 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.0-RC2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.10 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.11 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.12 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.13 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.14 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.4 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.5 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.6 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.7 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.8 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.2.9 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.0-BETA1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.0-RC1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.1 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.10 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.11 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.12 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.13 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.14 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.15 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.16 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.17 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.18 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.2 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.3 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.4 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.5 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.6 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.7 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.8 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - symfony/translation v3.3.9 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
    - Installation request for symfony/http-kernel (locked at v5.0.5) -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.5].
```

---

Подскажите возможно альтернативу этому пакету или болеее правильный путь по локализации дат. С этим вопросом ранее не сталкивался, да и Ларавел изучать стал недавно.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение, вместо:

```php
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->published_at)->format('j F Y')
```

Нужно использовать:

```php
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->deleted_at)->translatedFormat('j F Y')
```